# How to write log has token trace per request

Tags: go, logging, nanoid

I user gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2 to write log and compress file log.
I config log like

```
func Init() {
    file := &lumberjack.Logger{
        Filename:   "info" + ".log",
        MaxSize:    20, // mb
        MaxBackups: 5,
        Compress:   true,
    }
    id, err := gonanoid.New()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    Log = log.New(file, id+" ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime)
}
```

But id was created once time when I start service. I want to create new id per request. This I usually do with java but got stuck and couldn't find it in Go.

Comment: Dont assign it to a variable. Generate a new id everytime you need it